# javascript retrieve value from json

Tags: javascript, json

How to get value from `[object Object]` in javaScript.
i have a json response from php which i pass in javascript .
i want GPSPoint_lat,GPSPoint_lon all value.

var jArray = ;

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jArray);
```

i got [object Object] how i retrive the all value from obj.

my json string is-

```
{
   "Account": "dimts",
   "Account_desc": "Adminstrator",
   "TimeZone": "Asia/Calcutta",
   "DeviceList": [
      {
         "Device": "dl1pb1831",
         "Device_desc": "DL 1PB 1831",
         "EventData": [
            {
               "Device": "dl1pb1831",
               "Timestamp": 1387790572,
               "Timestamp_date": "2013/12/23",
               "Timestamp_time": "14:52:52",
               "StatusCode": 61472,
               "StatusCode_hex": "0xF020",
               "StatusCode_desc": "Location",
               "GPSPoint": "28.52802,77.14041",
               "GPSPoint_lat": 28.52802,
               "GPSPoint_lon": 77.14041,
               "Speed": 12.9,
               "Speed_units": "km/h",
               "Heading": 193.6,
               "Heading_desc": "S",
               "DigitalInputMask": 3,
               "DigitalInputMask_hex": "0x03",
               "Index": 0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Device": "dl1pb7520",
         "Device_desc": "DL 1PB 7520",
         "EventData": [
            {
               "Device": "dl1pb7520",
               "Timestamp": 1387790574,
               "Timestamp_date": "2013/12/23",
               "Timestamp_time": "14:52:54",
               "StatusCode": 61472,
               "StatusCode_hex": "0xF020",
               "StatusCode_desc": "Location",
               "GPSPoint": "28.56589,77.05268",
               "GPSPoint_lat": 28.56589,
               "GPSPoint_lon": 77.05268,
               "Speed": 29.9,
               "Speed_units": "km/h",
               "Heading": 91.4,
               "Heading_desc": "E",
               "DigitalInputMask": 3,
               "DigitalInputMask_hex": "0x03",
               "Index": 0
            }
         ]
      },
```

Comment: Try a `console.log(obj)` in the browser console. If you're `alert`ing Javascript objects, you'll always get `[object Object]` because that's the Javascript string representation (string cast) of an object.

Comment: Please specify which value you want, all is the whole object

Comment: In the future check your JSON against a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Have you tried with stringify. just try JSON.stringify(obj). you will get string of whole data. is that what you want or you want to loop through object ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at javascript tutorial

```
obj['key_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects work as an array. You can access to an element with a key:

```
obj['Account']  // returns dimts
obj.Account // works also
```

You should read some tutorial about it, like [JSON: What It Is, How It Works, & How to Use It](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

Please retrive the value as

```
var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['return'] ); ?>; 
var obj = JSON.parse(jArray);
var value=obj.Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have zero experience in php so I don't know what's the resulting object from your first line of code. But assuming `jArray` is a json object with the structure defined in your question...you access its values as shown below...

```
jArray.Account;
jArray.DeviceList[0].Device; //access the device property of the first object in the DeviceList array
jArray.DeciveList[0].EventData.StatusCode;
```